# Can you check whether a table exists via the Cloud Spanner API? (in Node.js)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner, gcloud-node

How can i detect table exist or not in database by table name?
there is not like:

```
database.exist('some table name')
```

I write my function:

```js
const queryTableExist = (tableName) => {
    return {
        sql: `SELECT t.table_name FROM information_schema.tables AS t WHERE t.table_catalog = '' and t.table_schema = '' and  t.table_name='${tableName}'`
    };
};
let tableExist = (tableName, cb) => {
    const query = queryTableExist(tableName);
    database.run(query, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(`${err}\n${query}`);
            cb(err);
        }

        cb(err, rows.length > 0);
    })
};
```

is there any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the [google-cloud-node](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node) client library and the [Cloud Spanner](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/tree/master/packages/spanner) package:

You can either call call table.create() and handle the error:

```js
var schema =
  'CREATE TABLE Singers (' +
  '  SingerId INT64 NOT NULL,' +
  '  FirstName STRING(1024),' +
  '  LastName STRING(1024),' +
  '  SingerInfo BYTES(MAX),' +
  ') PRIMARY KEY(SingerId)';

table.create(schema, function(err, table, operation, apiResponse) {
  if (err) {
    // Error handling omitted.
  }

  operation
    .on('error', function(err) {})
    .on('complete', function() {
      // Table created successfully.
    });
});
```

Or you can try to get a reference to the table and then check for a null object:

```js
var instance = spanner.instance('my-instance');
var database = instance.database('my-database');
var table = database.table('my-table');
```

Comment: Thank you... @Dominic Preuss

'var table = database.table('my-table');' 

it never return null - as i understood it maybe a bug.
I think while it not returning NULL.. my way is better..

Comment: The second solution here won't work -- there's no API call when calling `database.table(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

`Google Spanner API` currently does not support `exists` function to discover which table exists. So you'll need to query it yourself at the moment.

**the highest performance way to get your answer**

*Get all tables that exist*

```sql
SELECT
    t.table_name
FROM
    information_schema.tables AS t
WHERE
    t.table_catalog = '' AND t.table_schema = ''
```

*Find out if certain tables exist*

```sql
SELECT
    t.table_name
FROM
    information_schema.tables AS t
WHERE
    t.table_catalog = '' AND t.table_schema = '' AND
    t.table_name = 'yourTableNameA' OR
    t.table_name = 'yourTableNameB' OR
    t.table_name = 'yourTableNameC'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to request the DDL from the database and check for a `CREATE TABLE <your-table-name-here> ( ...` statement with a regular expression:

```
var instance = spanner.instance('my-instance');
var database = instance.database('my-database');

function databaseHasTable(database, tableName) {
  return database.getSchema().then(function (data) {
    var statements = data[0];
    var matcher = new RegExp('^create table ' + tableName + ' \\(', 'i');
    var results = statements.filter(function (item) {
      return matcher.test(item);
    });
    return results.length == 1;
  });
}

// This should print out true or false depending on the table being there.
databaseHasTable(database, 'my-table').then(console.log);
```